# Planar Graphs Question

Tags: proof-writing, graphing-functions, planar-graphs

I'm having some trouble with planar graphs. Two questions I was stuck on were:

1. Prove that each planar graph on $n \gt 3$ vertices will have a minimum of $4$ vertices of degree $5$ at most.
2. Let's say you are provided a planar graph on $17$ vertices and that there is a drawing of such a graph with $17$ faces (countries). Prove that such a graph has vertex with degree $3$ or less.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a proof by contradiction.
For (1), I showed multiple cases.
For (2), I solved for the number of edges then assumed to the contrary that all vertices are of degree 4.

Answer (score 1):

The tool you want is the Euler characteristic:

http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_characteristic

For a planar graph, $V+F=E+2$. Don't forget to count the "outside" as a face.

Comment: Hm, interesting. So to prove the above two questions, do I just prove it completely... algebraically? Sorry - I don't have a lot of time at the moment, I will be sure to look at the Euler Characteristic more in detail when I have time tonight/tomorrow.

Comment: Pretty much, yes. In fact, one of the proofs is described on that page. ;-)

Comment: Sorry, I don't entirely understand how I'm meant to incorporate the degree into the euler characteristic.